# How to fetch the value of body.data[0].images.fixed_height.url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, console

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

var xhr = $.get("http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=ryan+gosling&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC&limit=5"); 
    xhr.done(function(data) { console.log("success got data", data); });
    </script>
```

This is the response body from giphy:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there... why are you starting with body ? check [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/5wwtm794/1/)

```
var xhr = $.get("https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=ryan+gosling&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC&limit=5");
xhr.done(function(data) {
  console.log( data.data[0].images.fixed_height.url);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below

```
Xhr.done (function (data) {<br>
          Console.log ("success got data", data);<br>
          // How to check with log<br>
          Console.log (data [0] .images.fixed_height.url + "");<br>
});
```

Comment: nope it didnt work'd ,
it shows "Uncaught ReferenceError: Console is not defined"
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'images' of undefined

Comment: @The_Techie_next_door you need data.data[0] see my answer

Answer (score 0):

From you printscreen you need to console the following for the url:

```
 console.log( data.data[0].images.fixed_height.url);
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/a2Lfg20g/

the first `data` is the response body the second `data` is the array of object from the response body

Comment: dos.html:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

Comment: then that means your first item in the array doesn't have a url property or a parent property

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

var xhr = $.get("http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=ryan+gosling&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC&limit=5"); 
    xhr.done(function(data) { console.log("success got data", data.data[0].images.fixed_height.url); });
    </script>
```